# How to change PayPal subscription account?

Tags: paypal

I implemented PayPal subscription on my site, using PayPal smart button.
The generation of subscription plans implemented on the site via PayPal subscription API v1.

Is there a possibility to implement a "change PayPal account" button for our clients? So that a client could keep the subscription status but switch the account the payments are charged from?

Answer (score 0):

The client id of the button and the client id + secret for which the product and billing plan are created must be the same.

You can reuse the API code but you must create the product and plan for each account.

Comment: Hi Preston, thank you for your answer. But that is impossible. So, do we have to create hundreds of similar products and plans for each attempt to change the account? May be you did not get the question... We have a product and a plan. And a client is subscribed for that product-plan. And the client wants to continue using this subscription but to change the paypal account they are using for monthly payments. How to implement that?

Comment: Oh, no. Payers must cancel their existing subscription and subscribe again with the new account.

Comment: yes, thanks, that is what I suspected.